# Как изменить параметры url по клику?

Tags: javascript, ajax, modx, revo

Есть две кнопки 
`<a href="#" data-tpl="0" class="grid-three"><i class="fa fa-th"></i></a>
 <a href="#" data-tpl="1" class="list"><i class="fa fa-th-list"></i></a>`
работают аяксом, нужно для одной из них по клику прописать get параметр в url такой ?limit=10, как это сделать? Заранее благодарю

Comment: Непонятен вопрос, уточните.

Comment: При клике на `<a href="#" data-tpl="0" class="grid-three"><i class="fa fa-th"></i></a>` идет переход на http://site.ru/?limit=100000 а нужно задать просто http://site.ru/, без `?limit=100000`